# I Can upload images but cannot view them.(Paperclip S3 )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

I uploaded images to Amazon S3, but they're not displaying.
Image can upload but cannot view them. 
I am using rails5.2 , ruby 2.4

where i get the solution for this ?

```
Model.rb
has_attached_file :avatar,
                    styles: { medium: '400x400#' },
                    storage: :s3,
                    s3_credentials: "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml",
                    url: ":s3_domain_url",
                    path: "/uploaded_data/:class/:id/:basename.:extension",
                    s3_protocol: 'https'
```

```
view 
<%= image_tag @product.avatar.url %>
```

Comment: which URL you are getting can you please share?

Comment: https://xxxxxx.s3.amazonaws.com/uploaded_data/sales_items/421036/index.jpeg

Comment: Did you tried to fetch URL from console? do image exist on s3 as per path?

Comment: sorry ... not try yet

Comment: please check and acknowledge here :)

Comment: How to feth url from console ?

Comment: fetch using Product.last.avatar.url and track that path whether image is present as per that path or not, then compare  url fetched from console with the actual path. you may get some idea